# Not copying support files for sub solution when building in the main solution

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution that contains multiple projects some of them are c# and some are VB.Net projects. I am working in VS 2013. In one of the vb.net projects I have a sub folder that contains multiple files that are set to copy when new. 
When I compile my solution it will create the sub folder and copy all the files into the bin debug folder as expected.

However when my solution is added to a larger solution the files are not being copied nor is the subfolder they live in created in the bin debug folder or anywhere else in that solutions directory folders.

There are other "sub" solutions in the main solution that have this working correctly but I see no difference between the settings of those solutions and mine.

Is there a know reason why this would happen when adding a solution to a parent solution?

Answer (score -1):

You should try switching the property to always create rather than create when new.